# Yielding files in a directory of directories without inner directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, yield-keyword

My task is to train a ML model. I want to yield the files to avoid memory problems in the future. I have stumbled upon a solution that I adjusted a bit. But the modification does not quite meet my needs. Assume the folder structure I have is like the following:

../

A/

2014-01-01

2014-01-05

2014-01-06

/B

2014-01-02

2014-01-06

...

So essentially in folder: test, I have subdirs like: A,B .. etc.
Within each of those subdirectories, I have dates: 2014-01-01, etc.

What I need my generator to do is to **yield me the files in datetime order, ignoring the directories themselves (order subdirectories does not matter, I can get the files first from B then from A, does not matter)**.

I have the following code atm:

```
def sort_func(x):
    x_ = x
    x = str(x)
    # dates - files
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d")
    # folder. Ignore
    except ValueError as e:
        return x_
    except Exception as e:
        raise(e)

p = pathlib.Path('../datasets/train/')

a = sorted(p.glob('**/*'), key=sort_func)
```

And this would output something like this:

```
[PosixPath('../datasets/train/A'),
 PosixPath('../datasets/train/A/2014-01-01'),
 PosixPath('../datasets/train/A/2014-01-02'),
 PosixPath('../datasets/train/A/2014-01-03'),
...]
```

i.e. I do not need the first path, and all the directory paths.

How do I omit these?

**EDIT:** Actually, it appears that glob returns a list... `p.glob('*/*')` seems to do the trick, but `sorted(.)` is giving me a list instead of yielding the files one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with the `is_file` method of the `Path` object:

```
a = sorted([path for path in p.glob('**/*') if path.is_file()], key=sort_func)
```